# sage 5.0 syntax error with execfile()

Tags: python, sage

the following is part of a .sage file I would like to be able to call in a session:

```
def projective_grid(m,n):  
    r"""
    The  mxn grid in projective space
    """
    g = graphs.Grid2dGraph(m,n)
    g = Graph(g)
    for i in range(m):
        g.add_edge(((i,0),(m-i-1,n-1),1))
    for j in [1..(n-2)]:
        g.add_edge(((0,j),(m-1,n-j-1),1))
    g.delete_edge(((0,0),(m-1,n-1)))
    g.add_edge(((0,0),(m-1,n-1),2))
    g.delete_edge(((m-1,0),(0,n-1)))
    g.add_edge(((m-1,0),(0,n-1),2))
    if n%2==1 and m == 2:
        g.delete_edge((0, (n-1)/2), (1, (n-1)/2))
        g.delete_edge((0, (n-1)/2), (1, (n-1)/2))
        g.add_edge((0, (n-1)/2),(1,(n-1)/2),2)
    if n == 2 and m%2==1:
        g.delete_edge(((m-1)/2, 0), ((m-1)/2, 1)) 
        g.delete_edge(((m-1)/2, 0), ((m-1)/2, 1)) 
        g.add_edge(((m-1)/2, 0), ((m-1)/2, 1),2)    
    pos = {}
    k = -1
    for i in [1..m]:
      for j in [1..n]:
        k+=1
        pos[k] = (j,i)
    g.set_pos(pos)
    return g
```

I can copy-paste this code into a sage session without raising an error, but when I try and call the file with execfile(), I get the following:

```
sage: execfile('/Users/WyattAlt/Desktop/thesis/stack_test.sage')
------------------------------------------------------------
   File "/Users/WyattAlt/Desktop/thesis/stack_test.sage", line 9
     for j in [1..(n-2)]:
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

If I replace the problematic parts with range(1,n-1) and similar, the problem goes away, but I'd like to understand why this isn't working.  Any ideas?  Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I'm on OS X 10.5.8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sage syntax and Python syntax differ in a few places, including in that range syntax.

Behind the scenes, the Sage console preparses what you input into standard Python:

```
sage: [1..10]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
sage: preparse('[1..10]')
'(ellipsis_range(Integer(1),Ellipsis,Integer(10)))'
```

in fact, even integer literals are wrapped:

```
sage: 10
10
sage: preparse('10')
'Integer(10)'
```

When you use `execfile`, which is a purely Python function, you're bypassing the Sage preparser.  If you want the equivalent, you can use `load`:

```
sage: !echo "print [1..10]" >> test.sage
sage: !cat test.sage
print [1..10]
sage: execfile("test.sage")
------------------------------------------------------------
   File "test.sage", line 1
     print [1..10]
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

sage: load("test.sage")
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Comment: No worries.  Two points: (1) don't forget to [accept answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) to your questions, and (2) there's also [ask.sagemath.org](http://ask.sagemath.org), which is like StackOverflow but just for Sage, and lots of the developers hang out there.

Comment: +1 on the ask.sagemath.org as being the first place to go - but luckily @DSM and a few others of us occasionally are here :)

Comment: As an addendum to this answer, I strongly suggest using `attach` instead of `load`, because then any changes in the file are reloaded; since Python does this dynamically, if you change `projective_grid` for some reason (adding functionality, say) in the middle of a session, you wouldn't have to restart or something.  I've used this a lot in the past.

Comment: @kcrisman: I've always found a `attach` a little black-magicky, leading to weird half-working states, given the way I code.. I can see how it could be useful for other people, though.

Comment: @DSM; okay, I'll retract the *strongly* part.  At any rate, it proves convenient in many contexts.